# Jquery Block UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Can I use Buttons on Jquery BlockUI for my application..I saw couple of examples here but I am not seeing any buttons like  OK or Close buttons? Can we use in Jquery Block Ui?

http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked out this demo: http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#dialog? Should contain everything you need.

Especially check out this part:

```
$('#no').click(function() { 
    $.unblockUI(); 
    return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation).

Comment: Yes I know we can do with Jquery UI Dialog but is there any way we can keep it in Jquery Block?